# On the definition of Lagrange's equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, textbook-erratum

Is it really Newton's third law eq (1.5) ? Isn't the 2nd? I found it on "Abers Ernest Quantum mechanics".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that is, by definition, Newton's second law.